# Play Billing Library prevents uploading my App

Tags: android, expo, google-play, play-billing-library

I have an app built with Expo that I recently updated the SDKs for, this means I have no Android configuration files.

The App does not sell products, it only has a screen or section where some items they have are shown with a button that gives the possibility to go to the product store.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';


export default function Store(props) {

  const contextState = React.useContext(LanguageContext);
  const language = contextState.language;
  const Strings = Languages[language].texts;
  
  const onChangeScreen = (screen) => {
    props.navigation.navigate(screen);
  };

 return (

  <ScrollView
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>
    
<SafeAreaView>

    <View style={Styles.StoreScreen}>

    <Heading title={Strings.ST69}/>
    <FeaturedProducts/>

    <Heading title={Strings.ST71} button={() => onChangeScreen('types')}/>
    <ProductTypes/>

    <Heading title={Strings.ST70} button={() => onChangeScreen('products')}/>
    <LatestProducts/>

    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>

      );

}
```

But no products are sold in the Application, we only show the link to the store.

When I try to upload it to Google Play Console, it prevents me from doing so for the following reasons:

**Error
We have detected that one or more of the app bundles included in this version use the following versions of the Play Billing Library.
4.1.0**

**These are unsupported versions of Google Play Billing. Please upgrade to a supported version to publish this app. More information**

**Error
This app targets Android 14 and up. Your current version of Play Billing Library does not support Android 14. To target the latest version of Android, update your Play Billing Library version to version 5.2.1, 6.0.1, or later.**

I have searched for the dependencies, without success, including the node_modules dependencies

I don't know how to find any dependencies my application may have on this library. The only reference to everything related to billing is the following:

```
public function __construct($data = NULL) {
\GPBMetadata\Google\Api\Billing::initOnce();
parent::__construct($data);
}
```

Can you guide me a little with this error?

Since this is an Expo app, we don't have any other Andriod configuration files.

```
{
  "name": "ejercicio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.8.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.7.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.13",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "2.2.0",
    "expo": "^50.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
    "expo-av": "~13.10.4",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.11.0",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.7",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.8.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~12.8.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~6.4.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.24.9",
    "expo-video-player": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "hex-to-rgba": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-inviewport": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.11.4",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you run ./gradlew app:dependencies command and check in the tree which dependency exactly includes PlayBilling and what's the version of it? Then you can either force a higher version manually... 
Or you can downgrade the targetSdk in the first place if you have lots of outdated 3rd parties, though I wouldn't call it the best solution here

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PineapplePie , the project is created with Expo and it does not allow me Android commands. If you have another idea for discovering project dependencies, I would be happy to hear from you